# Scraping data from a complicated website in R (rvest package)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

For a research project I would like to extract all course information from every program in every faculty. I have practiced quite a bit with scraping data from websites but the website of my university seems to be coded differently than the websites I practiced on.

This is the link to the website:
https://ocasys.rug.nl/current/catalog

My goal is to make a script that can extract all the programme names with a corresponding hyperlink to the curriculum. A similar script could then be used to extract all the course names with a corresponding course code within each curriculum of each programme. Ultimately, these course codes could be used to generate URLs that lead to each unique course page which could be scraped for the relevant data.

[[This is where the information that I need is located - stored in this  element: name + hyperlink. This information is, per programme, stored in a li. element if I understand correclty. This prompted me to try and extract all of these li. elements in order to extract all the 'a']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbSi.png)

I have tried a lot of ways to extract it, but so far I have been very unsuccesfull. To be sure I did not do anything wrong I also extracted data from other websites with the same scripts, which was not a problem. It seems that I cannot define the element which I want to extract.

This is the script I use. I hope that someone has more experience in this that I have, and would be able to identify what I should put as an input in the html_elements() function, since the .css-105mfs8 does not seem to work.

```
#1 Setup Packages

library(pacman)
p_load('rvest', 'rlang')

#2 Load Website Course Data
URL = 'https://ocasys.rug.nl/current/catalog'
document = read_html(URL)

html_programmes <- document %>% html_elements('li.css-105mfs8')

a_element <- html_programmes %>% html_element("a") 

programme_urls <- html_products %>% 
  html_element("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") 

programmes <- data.frame( 
  programme_urls, 
  #corresponding name
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page and DOM tree you are seeing in your browser's element inspector is modified by javascript, meaning that content that gets loaded into revest is quite different and those selectors will not work there. You can turn JS off in your browser for that particular page to get an idea of what is still available in rvest.

Though the whole catalogue is in a single JSON - https://ocasys.rug.nl/api/faculty/catalog/2022-2023 - and it can be transformed into tabular form. Few  notes what's happening here - `hoist()` pulls some specific elements from nested list, `unnest_longer()` keeps the number of columns but adds rows (i.e we start with a list of 14 deprtaments and after `unnest_longer()` we have a list of 434 programs), `map_chr()` is used to turn list of 1..2 items into strings (some programs have 2 languages, most have 1).

More on rectangling - https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html .

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

faculty <- fromJSON("https://ocasys.rug.nl/api/faculty/catalog/2022-2023", simplifyVector = FALSE) %>% 
  tibble(faculty = .) %>% 
  hoist(faculty, "titleEN", "programs") %>% 
  unnest_longer(programs) %>% 
  hoist(programs, "language", "levels", programTitle = "titleEN", "code") %>% 
  mutate(language = map_chr(language, \(x) paste0(x, collapse = ", "))) %>% 
  mutate(levels = map_chr(levels, \(x) paste0(x, collapse = ", "))) %>% 
  mutate(url = paste0("https://ocasys.rug.nl/current/catalog/programme/",code)) %>% 
  select(-c(programs, faculty))
```

Result:

```r
faculty
#> # A tibble: 434 × 6
#>    titleEN                 language levels   programTitle            code  url  
#>    <chr>                   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                   <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  BACHELOR "BSc Astronomy"         50205 http…
#>  2 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  MASTER   "MSc Applied Physics "  60436 http…
#>  3 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  BACHELOR "BSc Computing Science" 56978 http…
#>  4 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  MASTER   "MSc Biomedical Engine… 6622… http…
#>  5 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  MASTER   "MSc Energy and Enviro… 60608 http…
#>  6 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  EXCHANGE "BSc Courses for Excha… WBEX… http…
#>  7 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  MASTER   "MSc Physics: Quantum … 6020… http…
#>  8 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  BACHELOR "BSc Pharmacy "         56157 http…
#>  9 Science and Engineering ENGLISH  BACHELOR "Pre-master/Fast-track… Pre-… http…
#> 10 Science and Engineering DUTCH    EXCHANGE "BSc Courses for Excha… WBEX… http…
#> # … with 424 more rows
glimpse(faculty)
#> Rows: 434
#> Columns: 6
#> $ titleEN      <chr> "Science and Engineering", "Science and Engineering", "Sc…
#> $ language     <chr> "ENGLISH", "ENGLISH", "ENGLISH", "ENGLISH", "ENGLISH", "E…
#> $ levels       <chr> "BACHELOR", "MASTER", "BACHELOR", "MASTER", "MASTER", "EX…
#> $ programTitle <chr> "BSc Astronomy", "MSc Applied Physics ", "BSc Computing S…
#> $ code         <chr> "50205", "60436", "56978", "66226-5506", "60608", "WBEXFA…
#> $ url          <chr> "https://ocasys.rug.nl/current/catalog/programme/50205", …
```

Or alternatively something like this, allow `simplifyVector` in `fromJSON()` (it's enabled by default), unnest (almost) everything and hope for the best:

```r
fromJSON("https://ocasys.rug.nl/api/faculty/catalog/2022-2023") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest(programs, names_sep = ".") %>% 
  unnest(status, names_sep = ".") 
#> # A tibble: 434 × 13
#>    id      code  titleEN titleNL progr…¹ progr…² progr…³ progr…⁴ progr…⁵ progr…⁶
#>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <list>  <list>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 2a2243… <chr>   <chr>   "BSc A… "BSc S… 50205  
#>  2 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 426809… <chr>   <chr>   "MSc A… "MSc A… 60436  
#>  3 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 785b8f… <chr>   <chr>   "BSc C… "BSc C… 56978  
#>  4 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 813944… <chr>   <chr>   "MSc B… "MSc B… 66226-…
#>  5 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 3a1b3d… <chr>   <chr>   "MSc E… "MSc E… 60608  
#>  6 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… eda736… <chr>   <chr>   "BSc C… "BSc C… WBEXFA 
#>  7 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… f2b8f8… <chr>   <chr>   "MSc P… "MSc P… 60202-…
#>  8 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 030967… <chr>   <chr>   "BSc P… "BSc F… 56157  
#>  9 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… a786ea… <chr>   <chr>   "Pre-m… "Pre-m… Pre-Fa…
#> 10 2591c6… fwn   Scienc… Scienc… 8fa491… <chr>   <chr>   "BSc C… "BSc C… WBEXIE 
#> # … with 424 more rows, 3 more variables: status.year <chr>,
#> #   status.visible <lgl>, status.export <lgl>, and abbreviated variable names
#> #   ¹​programs.id, ²​programs.language, ³​programs.levels, ⁴​programs.titleEN,
#> #   ⁵​programs.titleNL, ⁶​programs.code
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @MinkSieders, glad to hear. To indicate that an answer here in Stackoverflow was working for you, feel free to mark it as *Accepted*